# Print javascript block my link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plugins, printing

i found a little script for print a div but when i click on the button for print and i close the print window, all my dropdown list filter (isotope) and my dropdown menu is not working.

There is not event when i click

Here's my print script:

```
    <?php 
    require_once('/connexion.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM plaquettes";
    $results = $connexion->query($sql);
    $plaquettes = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $i=1; 

    $titreformat= $p->titre;

    $titreformat = enleverCaracteresSpeciaux($titreformat); 

    foreach($plaquettes as $p) { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function printContent(el){
        var restorepage<?php echo $i ?>= document.body.innerHTML;
        var printcontent<?php echo $i ?>= document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printcontent<?php echo $i ?>;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = restorepage<?php echo $i ?>;


    }

    </script>

<?php $i++; } ?>
```

My html with the button

```
                    <div id="mydiv<?php echo $i ?>" class="hidden_print" >
                <table class="print_header">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Société :</b> <?php echo $p->societe ?></td>
                        <td><img src="img/<?php echo $p->societe ?>logo.png" alt="Logo de la société"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div >
                    <h1><?php echo $p->titre ?></h1>

                        <ul>
                            <li><b>Client :</b> <?php echo $p->client ?></li>
                            <li><b>Département :</b> <?php echo $p->departement ?></li>
                            <li><b>Domaine :</b> <?php echo $p->domaine ?></li>
                            <li><b>Année de commande : </b><?php echo $p->annee ?></li>
                            <li><b>Montant : </b><?php echo $p->montant ?>€</li>
                            <li><b>Prestations : </b><?php echo $p->prestation ?></li>
                            <li><p><b>Détails : </b><?php echo $p->detail ?></p></li>

                        </ul>
                        <aside>
                            <img src="img/<?php echo $p->image ?>" alt="Photo des prestations">
                        </aside>
                    </div>


                </div>

<button id="buttonaprime" onclick="printContent('mydiv<?php echo $i ?>')" class="buttonaprime no-print"><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Imprimer la plaquette</button>
```

Thanks you !

Comment: Not sure about your issue BUT you are inserting script tag inside a foreach loop??? I'm not a PHP dev but really i don't get the logic behind it

Comment: Hm my foreach loop is outside the script, but i dont think this is the problem, because i already do this and i got no issue, th php work great ^^

Comment: The problem is that on each foreach loop iteration, you are redefining a `printContent()` method, it doesn't make sense. You can only have one method called `printContent()`

Comment: I add printContent<?php echo $i ?>() to the function name and to the button, but i still got this problem with my filter and my navmenu

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37484523/print-javascript-block-my-link/37485324#37485324)

Comment: And don't use javascript in php loop you just need to use one function that will get div id from print button click....

Comment: @Hightline Glad that my answer works for you. I don't mind if you also up vote my answer. ;) :)

Comment: I need one more reputation point for use the vote up, i'm sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this css and use `onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv(divId)"` in print button.

We are making all element `display:none` and element(div) with class `.print-div` only `display:block` for printing screen. So that will only print those div with class `.print-div`

Use this css and javascript-jquery Function:

Css:

```
@media print {
  body * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .print-div, .print-div * {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Javascript function Not in php loop:

```
function addPrintClassAndPrintDiv(divId) {

   //remove .print-div class from all element if any 
     $(".print-div").removeClass("print-div"); 

   //add .print-div class to that div you want to print
     $("#"+divId).addClass("print-div");

   //print 
      window.print();
}
```

Also check this working snippet for reference.

```js
function addPrintClassAndPrintDiv(divId) {

   //remove .print-div class from all element if any 
     $(".print-div").removeClass("print-div"); 

   //add .print-div class to that div you want to print
     $("#"+divId).addClass("print-div");

   //print 
      window.print();
}
```

```css
.cntent {
  height:250px;
  width:600px;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:20px;
}

@media print {
  body * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .print-div, .print-div * {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv1">
    <p>
          1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv1')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv2">
    <p>
          2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv2')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv3">
    <p>
          3.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv3')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv4">
    <p>
          4.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv4')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv5">
    <p>
         5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv5')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv6">
    <p>
          6.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv6')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv7">
    <p>
          7.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv7')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv8">
    <p>
          8.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv8')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv9">
    <p>
         9. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv9')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv10">
    <p>
         10. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv10')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv11">
    <p>
         11. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv11')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv12">
    <p>
         12. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv12')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv13">
    <p>
         13. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv13')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv14">
    <p>
         14. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv14')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv15">
    <p>
         15. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv15')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv16">
    <p>
        16.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv16')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv17">
    <p>
        17.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv17')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv18">
    <p>
        18.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv18')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv19">
    <p>
         19. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv19')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv20">
    <p>
         20. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv20')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv21">
    <p>
         21. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv21')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv22">
    <p>
         22. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv22')">Print</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="cntent" id="myDiv23">
    <p>
         23. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe nostrum ullam eveniet pariatur voluptates odit, fuga atque ea nobis sit soluta odio, adipisci quas excepturi maxime quae totam ducimus consectetur?
    </p>
    <button onclick="addPrintClassAndPrintDiv('myDiv23')">Print</button>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I've a small problem with your answer, the visibility Hidden/visible make my print with one page with my div and manyh other page with blank.
When i put display none/block  instead of visibiity the print, create only blank page :(

Comment: I haven't tested it but this should work `body * { display: none;} .print-div * { display: block !important;}`  I will test and will let you know if there is any better way

Comment: Also check my edit.. that may help if your div always will fit in one page so that will print first page only and won't get other blank pages. Let me know if that won't work for you.

Comment: I do this     `body{
        max-height:1024px!important;
         overflow:hidden!important;
    }

  body * {
    visibility: hidden!important;
     
  }
  .print-div, .print-div * {
    visibility: visible !important;

  }
  .print-div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
  }`

And my page return always this that didnt change [link](http://prntscr.com/bahoc8). :((

Comment: Sorry that some stuff is not working Can you try this also `.print-div:last-child {
     page-break-after: auto;
}` you can add this class in print media query.. if this will work I will add it in answer. Also you can check providing borders to all element to see what is there in blank pages so you can find solution. then `html, body { height: auto; }` may also works. **Trial and error**

Comment: Arf, the code you give me again as no effect. I'm sure i past in the good file, i i delete my other style code for print only in this file, the print change.

Comment: Please check now.. I had never tried to run my code. I tried now and by some small trial and error. It has been fixed. Also check snippet for your reference. :)

Comment: Well, i do a Codepen for you [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMYMBB) I probably dont see my errors can you check please, i dont understand why this wont work ><. But anyway big thanks you for taking your time for help me !

Answer (score 1):

Lahar Shah's answer is great! accept it. :)

You don't have to repeat foreach block to make javascript function.

```
<?php 
require_once('/connexion.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM plaquettes";
$results = $connexion->query($sql);
$plaquettes = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$i=1; 

$titreformat= $p->titre;

$titreformat = enleverCaracteresSpeciaux($titreformat); 

foreach($plaquettes as $p) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function printContent(el){
    var restorepage<?php echo $i ?>= document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent<?php echo $i ?>= document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent<?php echo $i ?>;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage<?php echo $i ?>;


}

</script>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

just declare your function once like below. (el parameter points div to print)

```
<?php 
require_once('/connexion.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM plaquettes";
$results = $connexion->query($sql);
$plaquettes = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$i=1; 

$titreformat= $p->titre;

$titreformat = enleverCaracteresSpeciaux($titreformat); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printContent(el){
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage ;
}
</script>
```

Your code should work.

but, there is serious issue with printContent function.

this function override whole DOM at 'document.body.innerHTML = ' statement.

so, isotope's filter and other javascript event handler gone!

usually many javascript libraries initialize there events/effects when DOM ready, and your HTML DOM loaded at once!

okay, There is two options you can choose.

first, use iframe for print partial DIV you want. like..

```
function printContent(el) {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.id = 'printFrame';
  iframe.src='about:blank';

  document.body.appendChild(iframe); 
  iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
  setTimeout(function() { // for IE
    iframe.contentWindow.focus();
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
  });
}
```

second. initialize again (like jquery, isotope, ... etc) after print. (not recommended)

```
function printContent(el){
    var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
    var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
    // now re-initialize again
    ...
}
```

good luck! and please remember PHP codes runs on server-side and JavaScript codes on client-side. :)